# can't find /dev/sda1 on mac ec2 instance

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount

I just started developing on iOS. I have a aws mac ec2 instance running the latest Catalina AMI

Have the default EBS root vol attached

[image]

but I can't seem to find the device

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-xxx /Users % diskutil info /dev/sda1    
Could not find disk: /dev/sda1
```

Here are some info from disktutil

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-xxx /Users % diskutil list                                                                                           
/dev/disk0 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *32.2 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         32.0 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +32.0 GB    disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     16.3 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 79.3 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.0 GB    disk2s5
```

I want to know the mount point of this block device so I can find how much disk space is free.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/sda1` is a placeholder name for the root volume.  Even on Linux systems, unless they are quite old, they won't have a `/dev/sda1` partition on the server.  On Linux, it's likely to be called `/dev/xvda1` or `/dev/nvme0n1p1`.

For MacOS, I'm not familair with the standards they use, but off the top of my head, I was going to say `/dev/disk0`, but looking closer, it says `/dev/disk0` is external and `/dev/disk1` is internal, so, I'm really not sure what's going on.

Comment: Similar boat, but I'd expect EBS to show up as external on an AWS Mac Mini.  EBS is a network attached device.  Normally there's some nvme hardware to increase the speed on normal hosts, so the drive appears as an internal device, but since the Mac Mini has one nvme port, AWS no doubt has to use some sort of USB adapter that looks like an external device to the OS.